# How do I make Google App Engine python SDK Remote API work with local development server when server is bound to specific IP (not localhost)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using the remote api (`remote_api_shell.py`) works fine on the production server. However, it only works on the development server when the development server is serving on `localhost`. It does not work when the server is running on specific IP (for example, `dev_appserver.py --host=192.168.0.1`).

This is using the Python SDK. I'm kinda sure this worked on version `1.7.5`. It does not work on `1.7.6` or `1.8.0`.

Here's a specific case:

Run the server and let it bind to the default address (`localhost:8080`):

```
/path/to/dev_appserver.py myapp/app.yaml
INFO     2013-05-25 19:11:15,071 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-05-25 19:11:15,323 api_server.py:152] Starting API server at: http://localhost:39983
INFO     2013-05-25 19:11:15,403 dispatcher.py:98] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-05-25 19:11:15,405 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

Start the remote API shell, and it works fine:

```
$ ./remote_api_shell.py -s localhost:8080
Email: x@x
Password: 
App Engine remote_api shell
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:15:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1]
The db, ndb, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
dev~furloughfun>
```

However, if you start the server with a specified host:

```
/path/to/dev_appserver.py --host=192.168.0.1 myapp/app.yaml
INFO     2013-05-25 19:11:53,304 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-05-25 19:11:53,554 api_server.py:152] Starting API server at: http://localhost:44650
INFO     2013-05-25 19:11:53,633 dispatcher.py:98] Starting server "default" running at: http://192.168.0.1:8080
INFO     2013-05-25 19:11:53,634 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

Notice it says `Starting API server at: http://localhost:44650` even though the content is served at `http://192.168.0.1:8080`. Is this indicative that you can **only** run the remote api on localhost? Perhaps for security reasons?

Also, when you try the `remote_api_shell.py` now, you can only log in with a valid account (no bogus accounts allowed) and it immediately errors and terminates.

The console errors end with:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 200: OK
```

and the local development server outputs:

```
INFO 2013-05-25 19:24:06,674 server.py:528] "GET /_ah/remote_api?rtok=90927106532 HTTP/1.1" 401 57
```

Anyone know what's going on here?
Is it impossible to access the remote API other than on `localhost`?
Is it impossible to access the remote API (even on `localhost`) if your content is served on a specific IP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that api server doesn't have option to set host. `dev_appserver.py` has options to set host & port for content and admin server, and for api server only port (`api_port` option). Example:

```
dev_appserver.py --host=192.168.5.92 
                 --admin_host 192.168.5.92 --admin_port 9000 
                 --api_port 7000 .
```

Running this reports:

```
 api_server.py:153] Starting API server at: http://localhost:7000

 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://192.168.5.92:8080

 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://192.168.5.92:9000
```

Looking into the source of GAE dev_appserver, caller of the method of api_server which starts the server is module `devappserver2.py` and the line is:

```
apis = api_server.APIServer('localhost', options.api_port,
                             configuration.app_id)
```

You can see hardcoded host name `localhost`.

If you find no good workaround, I would suggest to *patch* `devappserver2.py` by introducing a new option and [report issue with patch attached](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3)?

Comment: There is also an undocumented `--api_host` option, see bug report:  [From Python's `dev_appserver.py`, the `--api_host` option is undocumented.](https://issuetracker.google.com/69324467)

Answer (score 1):

Now, at least from version 1.9.27 of the SDK, the option `--api_host` helps with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to this as the GAE file structure has changed. Mine was located at 
%ProgramFiles%\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\api_server.py
Inside this file you could see the definition for the API server

```
class APIServer(wsgi_server.WsgiServer):
  """Serves API calls over HTTP."""

  def __init__(self, host, port, app_id):
    self._app_id = app_id
    self._host = host
    super(APIServer, self).__init__((host, port), self)
```

I tried passing the port argument thru the GUI of the GAE App Launcher, it doesn't seem to work at all, so I just hardcoded this port, otherwise the port is being randomized. and that could also lead to connection errors to the remote api server.