# remote_api_shell.py with localhost dev_appserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

How can one connect using `remote_shell_api.py` to a development instance of Google App Engine started with `dev_appserver.py` (1.9.26+)?

From the command line I get:

> $ remote_api_shell.py -s localhost:8080 demo
>
> ...
>
> urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized Too many auth attempts.

When run from a script with something like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc

def fake_auth():
        return ('pw', 'pass')
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(
        None, path, fake_auth, servername=server,
        save_cookies=True, secure=False,
        rpc_server_factory=appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer
)
```

One gets:

> google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc.ClientLoginError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

I have traced back through the AppEngine code but it is not apparent whether (or how) one is to fake authentication to the local server.

When I try OAuth in the code, e.g.

```
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(server, path, secure=True)
```

It throws an HTTPS error.

When I set `secure` to `False` one gets `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized Too many auth attempts.`

It looks like there *should* be a way to authenticate to a development appserver, as there is code to that effect at `google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc.py:347` but I have not yet gleaned how to employ it.

Has anyone worked this out yet?

As reported: [code.google.com/p/googleappengine Issue 12465](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12465)

Comment: This post may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753192/how-do-i-make-google-app-engine-python-sdk-remote-api-work-with-local-developmen

Comment: Thanks @JoshTriiJohnston – I saw that post, but the problem is fundamentally different (i.e. connection vs. authentication), and the answer is from 2013, long before the OAuth patch.  Appreciate you looking into it though. Cheers

Comment: It struck me because of you using `localhost` vs the app server maybe starting with a `--host` option. Also you should be passing an `app_id` when using `ConfigureRemoteApi`. It would be in the format: `s~<app_id>`.

Comment: Thanks @JoshTriiJohnston – thanks to your comments I figured it out -- answer below, soon. :)

Answer (score 5):

The answer was to point the remote api at the API server.  When one starts the appserver, it'll print something like this:

```
api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:58262
dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8081
```

Then one may connect with e.g.

```
    remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(
        None, path, fake_auth, servername=server,
        save_cookies=True, secure=False,
        rpc_server_factory=appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer
    )
```

where `server` is `localhost:58262`.

If the first argument is not `None` then it appears it must be `dev~APPID` (for ones own `APPID`)

#### — or —

A simpler version:

```
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(
        server.encode('ascii'), path, secure=not local
    )
```

where `server` is the same as above, path is `/_ah/remote` and `local` is set to `True` when using the dev server.

If `server` is not ASCII encoded then hard to debug things will happen.

Comment: Awesome! You use s~ when pointing to a deployed app so I thought it may be the same locally.

Comment: Thanks @JoshTriiJohnston, really appreciate your comments.  Incidentally, if I recall correctly `s~` is the prefix when the deployed app uses the high replication database, otherwise (i.e. it's a legacy app with master/slave) it is just the `APPID`.

Comment: I have been struggling with this too since the last SDK update. I want to just remote shell into the local dev app server.
remote_api_shell -s localhost:port
When I use the web server port, I get 401. Using the api server port gets around the authentication. However, If I do something, for example with an ndb transaction, I get an error from context.py. It seems like there is no context.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I worked around this problem. I take advantage of a hook that the remote_api has, not sure if it is documented outside the source code, but is there.

Add the following lines in your appengine_config.py at the root directory of your app's files.

```
if (os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
    os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development')):
    remoteapi_CUSTOM_ENVIRONMENT_AUTHENTICATION = (
        'SERVER_SOFTWARE', [os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE']])
```

The effect will be that your app will consider all remote API requests on the development server as coming from an admin and let them through. This should be good enough for the development environment.

Answer (score 0):

gae123 answer work for me but I had customer authentication all ready so i used the following update

```
if (os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
    os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development')):
remoteapi_CUSTOM_ENVIRONMENT_AUTHENTICATION = ('SERVER_SOFTWARE', [os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE']])
else:
    remoteapi_CUSTOM_ENVIRONMENT_AUTHENTICATION = ('HTTP_X_APPENGINE_INBOUND_APPID', ['appID'])
```